# 4 to 1 MUX representation

Tags: multiplexer

Here's a representation of a 4 to 1 MUX that I found in a book called: **Introduction to computing systems from bits and gates to C/C++ & beyond** by *Yale N. Patt and Sanjay J. Pattel*

[image: 4 to 1 MUX representation taken from]

My question is why is there this kind of strokes with a number (1 and 2) in the input and output and select lines, I did notice that they probably mean the number of bits a line represents but I think there is no need to denote that since MUX inputs are always 1 bit the same applies for the output the only case that we need to specify the number of bits is for the select line.
Can anyone clarify this representation to me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MUX inputs are always 1 bit

This is incorrect. In the example you shared, the S input is two bits, not one.

A wider mux (i.e. 8:1, 16:1, ...) will have even more bits for the S input.

It's also possible to use the MUX symbol to represent a device that takes several N-bit data inputs and selects one of them to produce at the data output. Such a device is easily built by using N single-bit MUXes with shared S inputs.

Comment: by inputs I meant A, B, C and D and not the select wires and I made that clear in my question when I said: "the only case that we need to specify the number of bits is for the select line."

Comment: @oabdullae read the answer again ... the mux could be selecting from multiple 8 bit busses ... for example, A, B, C, D could each be an 8 bit bus, and OUT would then be an 8 bit bus

Comment: @jsotola oh ok I kinda get it now, but I guess this kind of mux that would take more than 1 bit in each input (excluding select wires) would be more complicated, is that correct?

Comment: select lines are not part of the inputs ... the complexity can not possibly stay the same if the signal bus size increases

Comment: @oabdullae are you familiar with a mechanical SPDT switch and a mechanical DPDT switch?

Comment: @oabdullae, if you have 8 muxes like in your diagram you can easily make a 4:1 MUX for an 8-bit bus. There are 8x as many resources (transistors, for example) required. Does that mean the complexity is greater or not? (how do you define complexity?)

Comment: @jsotola nope i've never heard of such things I'm still a beginner in digital electronics

Comment: @ThePhoton I think complexity should increase, the way i think of it is using 8 muxes as you said but i always doubt my thoughts because most of the time i find a simpler alternative 
my definition of complexity is using more electronic components in this case transistors

Comment: @oabdullae a mechanical switch is not digital electronics

Comment: @jsotola oh yeah sorry I didn't pay attention but how are these things relevant to electronics?